# How can I set the domain attribute in express-session based on the request origin?

Tags: node.js, express, cors, express-session

I'm using express session. I set the domain `domain: 'mydomain.com'` so that the session cookie can be set between subdomains- like *api.mydomain.com* and *staging.mydomain.com*.

But this prevents the `Set-Cookie` header from setting the cookie when testing with a localhost frontend. I get `Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url.`

So I need to make the domain attribute  change to localhost if the origin is localhost.

If I conditionally set the domain, we don't have access to `req`:

```js
  app.use(session({
      secret: 'very secret 12345', 
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
      cookie: {
        domain:
          req.get('origin').slice(0, 17) === 'http://localhost:' ? 'localhost' : 'mydomain.com',
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite:  none,
      },
    })
  );
```

This returns `ReferenceError: req is not defined`.

So I tried calling `session` in a custom middleware to get access to `req`:

```js
  app.use((req, res, next) =>
        session({
      secret: 'very secret 12345',
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
      cookie: {
        domain:
          req.get('origin').slice(0, 17) === 'http://localhost:' ? 'localhost' : 'mydomain.com',
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite:  none,
      },
    })
  );
```

But it doesn't work. It seems that with this, `res`, `req`, and `next` don't get passed in to the middleware function that `session()` returns. I also trying calling the function `session()` that returned -`session({..options..})()` , but that didn't work either.

How can I set the domain attribute based on the request origin?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to call the function and pass in `req`, `res`, and `next`

```js
  app.use((req, res, next) =>
    session({
      secret: 'very secret 12345', // to do, make environment variable for production
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
      cookie: {
        domain:
          req.get('origin').slice(0, 17) === 'http://localhost:' ? 'localhost' : 'mydomain.com',
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite:  none,
      },
      },
    })(req, res, next)
  );
```

Comment: @vodolaz095 How is the second way possible? Req would be undefined?

Comment: The original answer is right. The edit is incorrect. This question and answer should not have been down voted. Please read the question more carefully

Comment: req will be correct, expressjs has 2 types of middlewares - error handler one - `function(error, req,res,next)....` and ordinary one `function(req,res,next)...`. Session is 2nd type, ordinary one

Comment: It is not correct. `req` is undefined. Try it. It gives you `ReferenceError: req is not defined`. Think about it.  The `session` function is not the middleware that is run. The function that `session` returns is the middleware. So when `req.get('origin')` is run `req` has not been passed in.